# Infinite Loop parsing a table using htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I am trying to parse through TR's using HtmlAgilityPack and do something different with the 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc TD's.

I am almost there but my code (below) causes an infinite loop. It just repeats the first row over and over again:

```
        foreach (HtmlNode row in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table//tr"))
        {
            var node = row.SelectSingleNode("//td[1]");
            if (node != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Node: {0}", node.InnerText);
            }
        }
```

The raw HTML returned it correct. The table is also pretty standard:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Header 1</hr>
    <th>Header 2</hr>
    <th>Header 3</hr>
    <th>Header 4</hr>
    <th>Header 5</hr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
    <td>Cell 3</td>
    <td>Cell 4</td>
    <td>Cell 5</td>

    ...
  </tr>
</table>
```

The following code works but then it is not grouped by row so it is much harder to manipulate:

```
        foreach (HtmlNode node in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table//tr//td"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Node: {0}", node.InnerText);
        }
```

Comment: Did you try doing a .ToList() at the end of select nodes and seeing how many it returns, it might be an issue where the SelectNodes is not returning the enumerable correctly.

Comment: The element row has the correct amount of nodes.

Comment: Try using the list instead of the SelectNodes directly and see if the behavior is the same.

Comment: Do you see the node change each loop, or does it always stay the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine with your sample html

```
var res = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table//tr[td]")
             .Select(row => row.Descendants("td")
                                .Select(td => td.InnerText).ToList())
             .ToList();
```

Comment: It does but it just extracts all the items as a string which is what I am trying to avoid. I need to keep them grouped by row so I can create a class with each one.

Comment: @DavidBainbridge `It does but it just extracts all the items as a string` No.,  It returns `List<List<string>>`  (each rows has a `List<string>`). At least see the code, there is nothing like string concatination.